# g++ makefile, multiple cpp's each with there own main()

Tags: c++, makefile

I have several .cpp files that each are compiled separately into their own executables, I also want to use the functions in each of them with .h in a main executable. How do I go about doing this?

makefile

```
all: A B C
  g++ -o main.exe -std=c++11 A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp

A: A.cpp
  g++ -o A.exe -std=c++11 A.cpp


B: B.cpp
  g++ -o B.exe -std=c++11 B.cpp


C: C.cpp
  g++ -o C.exe -std=c++11 C.cpp
```

Comment: Split the functions out into a separate library.

Answer (score 2):

A C program cannot have two functions with the same name, `main` is not special in that.

My advice is to separate the `main` functions to their own CPP files and leave only the utility reusable functions in the common files:

```
all: A B C
  g++ -o main.exe -std=c++11 all_main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp

A: A.cpp
  g++ -o A.exe -std=c++11 A_main.cpp A.cpp


B: B.cpp
  g++ -o B.exe -std=c++11 B_main.cpp B.cpp


C: C.cpp
  g++ -o C.exe -std=c++11 C_main.cpp C.cpp
```

An alternative would be to use conditional compilation to skip the undesired `main` definitions. But that would be quite messy.

Something like:

#### A.cpp

```
void funA()
{ /*...*/ }

#ifdef A_EXE
int main()
{
}
#endif
```

And then in the `makefile`:

```
A: A.cpp
  g++ -o A.exe -std=c++11 -DA_EXE A.cpp
```

This use of conditional compilation trick, although a bit hacky and not very extensible, is used some times to provide a small test case or sample program within the code of a library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `main()` in each of `A.cpp`, `B.cpp`, `C.cpp` is absolutely necessary, then you can put it under `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef STANDALONE_APP
int main(....) { ... }
#endif
```

and then pass `-DSTANDALONE_APP` for each of `A`, `B`, `C`...

Or maybe better use the advice of @rodrigo.

Comment: This pattern is used when the `main` in with the other functions is a unit-test for the other functions in the file.  If it's supposed to be compiled to a separate useful program normally, it's usually better to put that `main` in a separate file.